# Latent Fingerprint Matching

Tags: matching, fingerprint

I'm working on my project based on **Latent Fingerprint Matching**, and I need a free SDK for matching fingerprints which is easy to use and modify, and please mention the one you used before so I can get help in case of any problems.

Answer (score 0):

[NIST](http://www.nist.gov/) have a SDK for fingerprint recognition: [NBIS](http://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/ig/nbis.cfm).

It could be downloaded [here](http://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/ig/nigos.cfm).

Comment: @AhmadBukhari , Is it useful ?